# Testing with capybara and web mock rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, mocking, capybara

---

Hello!
I have a rails api and a front end on backbone.
My api makes a call to an external api to get some resources.

I want to make an integration test of the full app in capybara. I am using web-mock.

An snipped of my spec_helper:

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    stub_request(:get, "url.com/live/en/live/list.json").
      with(headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
      to_return(status: 200, body: body, headers: {})
  end  
(...)
end

def body
  "{\"version\":\"9\",\"sports\":[{\"id\":101,\"title\":\"Football\"},{\"id\":100,\"title\":\"Tenis\"}]}"
end
```

My feature test:

```
feature 'sports displayment' do
  scenario 'user access to the site' do
    visit root_path

    expect(page).to have_text("Football")
  end
end
```

The error displayed is `expected to find text "Football" in ""`
and if I embed a binding.pry on the controller it does not work (meaning that it is not going through it.

I am sure the app works, so it is a test problem.

A link to the app https://github.com/gerard-morera/bet_play

-------EDIT-------

I have been trying some new things that are reasonable but that is still not working. 
I have added selenium because default capybara diver does not support js, I have added `wait_for_ajax`, a method, to be sure that capybara is waiting for the ajax request and I as well enabled js for this scenario:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'sports displayment' do

  before(:all) do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
  end

  scenario 'user access to the site', js: true do
    visit '/'

    wait_for_ajax

    expect(page).to have_text("Football")
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @Gerard - can you post a link to a branch of your repo with the entire of the above setup?

Comment: Hi @SamJoseph, thanks for your help. This is the branch that concerns to this feature testing https://github.com/gerard-morera/bet_play/tree/feature-test

Answer (score 0):

You should try with

```
expect(page).to have_content("Football")
```